# how to proceed function().function()?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm looking to call functions like this:

`select().orderBy()` where firstly `select()` is called and after `orderBy()` is called.

To achieve it I have definig a method into the select method like this :

```
def select(self):
    if self.key is not None:
        self.request = """SELECT """ + self.key[0] + """ FROM """ + self.table
    else:
        self.request = """SELECT * FROM """ + self.table

    def where():
         self.request += """ WHERE """ + self.key[0] + """ = """ + self.value[0]
         return self.request
    def orderBy(key, value):
        self.request += """ ORDER BY """ + key + """ """ + value
        return self.request
    def groupBy(arg):
        self.request += """ GROUP BY """ + arg
        return self.request
    def limit(arg):
        self.request += """ LIMIT """ + arg
        return self.request
```

But I have this error message :

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'orderBy'
```

Does someone know how to do ?

Comment: Your `select` function returns nothing, so `None` is returned instead.

Comment: The `where`, `orderBy`, `groupBy` and `limit` functions don't look like methods to me; they should be methods *on the same class* and have `self` arguments.

Comment: Nesting your functions will **not** make them available on the returned string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Chaining methods (a fluent or generative API) only works if the preceding call returns an object that supports the next method; in `foo().bar()`, `foo()` must return an object that has a `.bar()` method. Your `.select()` method returns `None`, an object that won't support any of the other methods.

Your `select` function should return `self`:

```
return self
```

for the call to be chainable. You probably want the *other* calls to return `self` too, and not `self.request`. I'm assuming here that the other methods are indeed methods on the same class (your example is missing `self` parameters for each of them).

If you were trying to have those methods available only because you nested them inside the `select()` method, then that won't work *at all*. Those function objects are just un-used local names in the function body, they are not available on the returned object.

If those methods should not exist on the same class that defines `select`, define a **new** class and have that class implement your extra methods. Have `select()` return an instance of that class:

```
class Selectable:
    # ...
    def select(self):
        column = '*' if new_clone.key is None else new_clone.key
        request = """SELECT {} FROM {}""".format(column, new_clone.table)
        return Query(request)

class Query:
    def __init__(self, request):
        self.request = request
    def where(self):
         self.request += """ WHERE """ + self.key[0] + """ = """ + self.value[0]
         return self
    def orderBy(self, key, value):
        self.request += """ ORDER BY """ + key + """ """ + value
        return self
    def groupBy(self, arg):
        self.request += """ GROUP BY """ + arg
        return self
    def limit(self, arg):
        self.request += """ LIMIT """ + arg
        return self
```

Note that each of the methods on `Query()` return `self` so you can continue to chain.

However, you are then manipulating the same instance, and won't be able to create separate query objects from a common base. SQLAlchemy does this better; it returns a *clone* of `self`, with the added changes:

```
def _clone(self):
    return type(self)(self.request)

def where(self):
    new_clone = self._clone()
    new_clone.request += """ WHERE {} = {}""".format(self.key[0], self.value[0])
    return new_clone
```

Now `base = Selectable().select()` and `filtered = base.where()` makes `filtered` a distinct clone, so you can continue to use `base` to build other queries.

(In reality, SQLAlchemy uses a [decorator](https://github.com/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/blob/64e72b58fd74db0c5c87407c824d08ad699e5e8e/lib/sqlalchemy/sql/base.py#L40-L46) that replaces `self` with a [newly created clone](https://github.com/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/blob/64e72b58fd74db0c5c87407c824d08ad699e5e8e/lib/sqlalchemy/sql/base.py#L308-L317)).

Comment: thank you Martjin for your anwser, I'm as of now returning self in select() and orderBy() etc methods. But now I have this error messahe : AttributeError: Screening instance has no attribute 'orderBy'

Comment: @JakyChane: I assumed that `orderBy` was a method on `Screening`. If they are just functions, they indeed won't work. Indent them and give them `self` arguments.

Comment: @JakyChane: alternatively, put those methods on a *new* class that models a select statement, and have `select()` return an instance of that class.

Comment: @JakyChane: I think I see what you were trying to do, and have adjusted my answer. I did revert and re-edit your question to make sure the question and answer pair still make sense together.